# Search for an example about relation between zeta functions and hodge numbers

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $S$ be a finite set of prime numbers and $X$ be a proper
smooth variety (reduced scheme of finite type) over $\text{Spec} \mathbb{Z} [1/S]$.
Let $p$ be a prime number not in $S$. I can consider the base change $X_{\mathbb{F}_{p}}$
over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ to which I can associate its zeta function $Z(X_{\mathbb{F}_{p}})$.
I can also consider the base change $X_\mathbb{C}$ to which I can 
associate its Hodge numbers $h^{p,q}$.

My question is :

** Are there some S,p as above and some proper smooth variety $X$ and $Y$
over $\text{spec} \mathbb{Z}[1/S]$
such that $X$ and $Y$ have the same zeta function over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ but different Hodge
numbers ?**

In the mathoverflow discussion 
[Can one find the hodge number by counting points over finite fields?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/92958/)
an example is given which answers the question if I replace $\mathbb{F}_{p}$, $p$ prime,
by a general finite field $\mathbb{F}_{q}$, $q$ power of a prime. The idea of this 
example is to consider a supersingular elliptic curve over $\mathbb{F}_{q}$
such that the frobenius acts on $H^1$ by multiplication by $\sqrt{q}$ 
(in order to construct by product a variety whose cohomology looks like
cohomology of a projective plane ...) : of course, for the existence of such
an elliptic curve, a necessary condition is $2 \sqrt{q}$ integer so 
$q$ must be a square. This shows that this example cannot be easily changed 
to answer the question.
What I want is stronger : the zeta function over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ contains more information than
the zeta function over $\mathbb{F}_{p^{n}}$ for some $n$.

Finally, one remark to prevent eventual misunderstanding : the data in the question is the 
zeta function over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ for one particular prime $p$. It is known (for example
in [How much complex geometry does the zeta-function of a variety know](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19802/)) that the knowledge of the zeta functions on $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ for all but finitely many primes $p$ determine the Hodge numbers.

Comment: One can obtain examples of the type you want by restriction of scalars, i.e., if you have such examples over the ring of $S$-integers of a number field, then the restriction of scalars to $\mathbb{Z}[1/S]$ will give what you want. The point is that after base change to $\mathbb{C}$ the restriction of scalars is just a product and if $X_1$ and $X_2$ have the same number of points over each finite extension of $\mathbb{F}_q$, then the same will hold for the restriction of scalars over $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does the zeta function changes in a simple
way under restriction on scalars ?